# remove some token in twig.js1.16

Tags: twig.js

I want to remove tokens output_whitespace_pre, output_whitespace_post in twig.js1.16, output_whitespace_both and output,Since the data binding is done in Vue this could lead to syntax issues.

How should I do it in twig.js1.16?